# windows phone update error 8018830f

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-920, update, soft-reset

I try to update my phone yesterday, but after download i get the following message:

```
The update was downloaded, but couldn't be opened. (8018830f)
```

My phone is Nokia Lumia 920, i have ~20GB free space. I don't wanna rush with reset. Is someone else experience the same problem? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Updated date & time.
That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a common problem, however, there does not appear to be a (reliable) fix available.  Some users have reported clearing the download cache and restarting the download over wifi has helped.

Source:
http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/237622-amber-install-failure-8018830f-fault-code.html

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/error-8018830f-on-lumia-920/fe017735-5fb5-4235-8391-f9b68c686fcf

https://twitter.com/OchoaR/status/282277264081702912

Comment: You are absolutely right, there is no common salutations.It's no big deal but it's kind of anointing. Thank you for your time (:

Comment: btw today i try to change the regional settings, the update disappear, i don't know what is happening